# vk_api непонятная ошибка при отправке сообщения боту в беседе

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, бот

Недавно начал изучать vk_api. Накатал бота для беседы, но при отправке сообщения, получаю ошибку.

Код:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
import random
import requests
import time


def write_msg(peer, message):
    vk.method('messages.send', {'peer_id': peer,
                                'message': message, 'random_id': 0})

def write_msg2(id, message):
    vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id': id,
                                'message': message, 'random_id': 0})

token = "токен"
group_id = "id группы"

def main():
    bot_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
    longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(bot_session, group_id)
    while True:
        try:
            for event in longpoll.listen():
                if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                    print("got event new message")
                    if event.obj.peer_id != event.obj.from_id:
                        if event.obj.text.lower() == "привет":
                            write_msg(event.obj.peer_id, "в работе")
                    elif event.obj.peer_id == event.obj.from_id:
                        if event.obj.text.lower() == "привет":
                            write_msg2(event.obj.from_id, "в работе")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            time.sleep(3)



if __name__=='__main__':
    print("Запускаюсь...")
    main()
```

Ошибка:

```
    File "C:\Users\Georgiy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\vk_api\bot_longpoll.py", line 253, in check
    for raw_event in response['updates']
  File "C:\Users\Georgiy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\vk_api\bot_longpoll.py", line 253, in <listcomp>
    for raw_event in response['updates']
  File "C:\Users\Georgiy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\vk_api\bot_longpoll.py", line 214, in _parse_event
    return event_class(raw_event)
  File "C:\Users\Georgiy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\vk_api\bot_longpoll.py", line 160, in __init__
    if self.obj.peer_id < 0:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Не пойму в чем проблема и где ошибка? Буду рад любой помощи, можно хейтить)
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ: Это баг. Лечится понижением версии Long Poll API (например, до 5.80)